# Creating subscriptions on Azure ServiceBus with QPID JMS (AMQP 1.0)

Tags: azure, jms, amqp, servicebus

The servicebus client 2.1 now supports [AMQP 1.0](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/service-bus-amqp-overview/).

On MSDN there is an [article](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/java/how-to-guides/service-bus-amqp/) about how to use QPID.AMQP.JMS with Azure ServiceBus.

However, although I can connect to a predefined Topic and a Subscription, post messages and receive all of them, I cannot change the message selector or create a new topic/subscription.

My goal is to be able to connect to a Topic and dynamically create subscriptions based on different filters using org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.jms.

Questions:

1/ How can I create a new topic.

```
Topic newTopic = (Topic) session.createTopic("newtopic");
session.createProducer(newTopic); // returns error
```

- This maybe because JMS doesn't support administration of the topics though... although I'm sure I've read somewhere it should create a topic if it doesn't exist.?

2/ How can I create a new subscription with a different message selector via Jms?

```
// This still gives me all messages no matter what I put in the 'class' property.
TopicSubscriber subscriber = session.createDurableSubscriber(topic, "sub1", "class = 'boo'", false);
```

Thanks,
Phil.

Comment: Maybe this will explain it all!
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/java/how-to-guides/service-bus-topics/#bkmk_HowToReceiveMsgs

Answer (score 3):

The AMQP 1.0 protocol deliberately left entity creation / management outside of it's scope, you'll need to create your topics and subscriptions beforehand using provider-specific mechanics for this ([This post](http://kellabyte.com/2012/10/20/clarifying-amqp/) has a good explanation on why).

In the case of Service Bus, you can either use the [Azure SDK](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/downloads/), the portal (in case you don't need to do it programmatically), or their [REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh780750.aspx) for this.

Hope it helps!

Comment: One would hope that provider specific mechanics for queue creation and management would be performed by sending AMQP messages, not by some other means.